# MQ Client 7.5 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

I need help with this error. Could you tell me if this is client or server related issue? I use WMQ Client 7.5. I set up connection, certificates properly and it works on development evniroment. As usual on production there are problems. I read some articles and there was mentioned that I need to do following:

> If this is a production queue manager, then you could stop trying to
>   use a userid that is an MQ Administrator and instead, use a
>   non-administrator userid to access the queue manager.

But I don't specify any account ID while connecting to MQ Server. I am really lost now. Any advice would be apriciated.

Comment: You need to look in the AMQERR01.LOG on the queue manager to discover the exact reason. Without that information we are just guessing as to what the problem might be. Please add that information to your question.

Comment: You didn't specify what version of MQ server or client is being used and the authorization mechanisms vary greatly across versions.  I would highly suggest reading the information wiki for the [tag:websphere-mq] tag and in particular the section stating what information to provide when asking MQ questions.  Stack Overflow does not work like a forum and you will not have a chance to repeat question/response iterations.  When you update your question with additional information it might become answerable. As written though the question is a dupe.